# Is there any unique identifier which shouldn't be modified during reboot / install / uninstall app?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

Is there any unique identifier which shouldn't be modified during reboot / install / uninstall app?

Need a device's Universally Unique Identifier

Having issues with this (deviceid = device.uuid) we are unable track whether he is new user or old user based on device.

In Android when we reset phone device.uuid is going to be change.

In Windows when we Re-install device.uuid is going to be change.

Note: Not tested in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

@Sannith,
You did not say too much about requirements, so here are two (2) plugins that may get you what you are looking for.

[imeiplugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imeiplugin) - Get The Real IMEI Number on Device
[cordova-plugin-sim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sim) -  gets data from the SIM card like the carrier name, mcc, mnc and country code and other system dependent additional info.

What is the IEMI? – From [imei.info](http://www.imei.info/)

> Every mobile phone, GSM modem or device with a built-in phone / modem has a unique 15 digit IMEI number. Based on this number, you can check some information about the device, eg brand or model.